# Add .class to ant build classpath

Tags: ant

I am trying to add a few folders to the classpath in our ant build file.

```
<dirset dir="${env.WT_HOME}/codebase/com/lcs/wc/"> 
    <include name="flexbom flexQuerySpec flextype foundation material util moa" />
</dirset>
```

All these folders (i.e. 'flexbom' 'flexQuerySpec'...) are inside codebase/com/lcs/wc folder. Each folder has several class files. I want to add all these class files to the path.

Above script doesn't seem to be working. I am still getting class not found for these folder/packages.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `<include>` elements in a `<fileset>` or [`<dirset>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) specify matching patterns, one pattern per element, rather than lists.

An alternative is to use the `includes` attribute instead like this:

```
<dirset dir="${env.WT_HOME}/codebase/com/lcs/wc/"
        includes="flexbom flexQuerySpec flextype foundation material util moa" />
```

Or multiple include elements:

```
<dirset dir="${env.WT_HOME}/codebase/com/lcs/wc/">
  <include name="flexbom" />
  <include name="flexQuerySpec" />
  <include name="flextype" />
  <include name="foundation" />
  <include name="material" />
  <include name="util" />
  <include name="moa" />
</dirset>
```